# appendchild is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on nested array. When i am trying to insert data to a div by using `appendChild` It is throwing an error saying **Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null**

My Code goes hear

```
<script>
    var emp1 = [];
    emp1["Emsno"] = 10001;
    emp1["name"] = "jack";
    emp1 ["sall"] = 5000;

    var emp2 = [];
    emp2["Emsno"] = 10002;
    emp2["name"] = "Reck";
    emp2 ["sall"] = 5500;

    var emp3 = [];
    emp3["Emsno"] = 10003;
    emp3["name"] = "lama";
    emp3 ["sall"] = 5300;

    var emp4 = [];
    emp4["Emsno"] = 10004;
    emp4["name"] = "sam";
    emp4 ["sall"] = 6000;

    var emps = [emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4];

    var Employedisplay = document.getElementById("Employedisplay");

    function showEmployes(){
        var n = emps.length;

        for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            var emp = emps[i];

             for(var key in emp){

                var NewDiv = document.createElement("div");

                NewDiv.innerHTML = key + ": " + emp[key];

                Employedisplay.appendChild(NewDiv);

             }
             var NewBrk = document.createElement("br")
             Employedisplay.appendChild(NewBrk);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id = "MyArray"  value ="Show Emps" onclick="showEmployes()"/>
<hr>
<div id="Employedisplay"></div>
</body>
```

and it is working in this way

```
function showEmployes(){
        var n = emps.length;

        for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            var emp = emps[i];

             for(var key in emp){

                var NewDiv = document.createElement("div");

                NewDiv.innerHTML = key + ": " + emp[key];

                document.getElementById("Employedisplay").appendChild(NewDiv);

             }
             var NewBrk = document.createElement("br")
             Employedisplay.appendChild(NewBrk);
        }
    }
```

I am not understanding where i am going wrong in my first approach?

Comment: `var Employedisplay = document.getElementById("Employedisplay");` is executed before the element with id `Employedisplay` exists. Move the `<script>` block at the end of the document, right before the closing `</body>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/baprs8z2/

Answer (score 0):

The below line of code is executed even before the browser add the `#Employedisplay` element in DOM.

```
var Employedisplay = document.getElementById("Employedisplay");
```

So when you click the button, `Employedisplay` variable is `null`

It's better to bootstrap your code on page load, or you can get the #Employedisplay element at the start of `showEmployee` method.

```
<script>
    var emp1 = [];
    emp1["Emsno"] = 10001;
    emp1["name"] = "jack";
    emp1["sall"] = 5000;

    var emp2 = [];
    emp2["Emsno"] = 10002;
    emp2["name"] = "Reck";
    emp2["sall"] = 5500;

    var emp3 = [];
    emp3["Emsno"] = 10003;
    emp3["name"] = "lama";
    emp3["sall"] = 5300;

    var emp4 = [];
    emp4["Emsno"] = 10004;
    emp4["name"] = "sam";
    emp4["sall"] = 6000;

    var emps = [emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4];

    function bootstrap() {
        var Employedisplay = document.getElementById("Employedisplay");
    }

    function showEmployes() {
        var n = emps.length;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var emp = emps[i];

            for (var key in emp) {

                var NewDiv = document.createElement("div");

                NewDiv.innerHTML = key + ": " + emp[key];

                Employedisplay.appendChild(NewDiv);

            }
            var NewBrk = document.createElement("br")
            Employedisplay.appendChild(NewBrk);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="bootstrap();">
    <input type="button" id="MyArray" value="Show Emps" onclick="showEmployes()" />
    <hr>
    <div id="Employedisplay"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var emp1 = [];
    emp1["Emsno"] = 10001;
    emp1["name"] = "jack";
    emp1 ["sall"] = 5000;

    var emp2 = [];
    emp2["Emsno"] = 10002;
    emp2["name"] = "Reck";
    emp2 ["sall"] = 5500;

    var emp3 = [];
    emp3["Emsno"] = 10003;
    emp3["name"] = "lama";
    emp3 ["sall"] = 5300;

    var emp4 = [];
    emp4["Emsno"] = 10004;
    emp4["name"] = "sam";
    emp4 ["sall"] = 6000;

    var emps = [emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4];



    function showEmployes(){
    var Employedisplay = document.getElementById("Employedisplay");
        var n = emps.length;

        for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            var emp = emps[i];

             for(var key in emp){

                var NewDiv = document.createElement("div");

                NewDiv.innerHTML = key + ": " + emp[key];

                Employedisplay.appendChild(NewDiv);

             }
             var NewBrk = document.createElement("br")
             Employedisplay.appendChild(NewBrk);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" id = "MyArray"  value ="Show Emps" onclick="showEmployes()"/>
<hr>
<div id="Employedisplay"></div>
</body>
```